# NSRunAlertPanel caused performance issue on multithreading

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsalert, nsrunalertpanel

Occasionally I have to do a popup alert window in my Cocoa code segments. Previously I used `NSAlert` directly then have `runModal` to go while I found that the `NSRunAlertPanel` is more easier to achieve my goal. So I decided to switch all my alert functions to `NSRunAlertPanel`. It seemed okay at most time。

Now I'm adding multithreading. I found that `NSRunAlertPanel` appears clearly slower than `NSAlert` when calling back in the main thread.

Code segments:

Firstly I create a thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(tryRunLoop:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Then this function`tryRunLoop` in this thread call the alert window function in the main thread:

```
while(1)
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert:) withObject:anObject waitUntilDone:YES];
```

The function `showAlert` in main thread do the rest things:

```
NSRunAlertPanel(@"Warning:",@"Just testing", @"YES", nil, nil);
```

As time goes by the response of the popup window appears slower and slower.If I use `NSAlert` instead of `NSRunAlertPanel`, or did not run the popup method in main thread, the symptom should disappear.

I also found that the CPU usage was also different between these two methods. Obviously `NSAlert` costs low CPU usage while hitting the button all the time.

Is someone able to explain these phenomenons?

PS: I was not allowed to put the whole original project online so that I've created a simple Cocoa project in Github to simulate the symptom and the [URL](https://github.com/othercat/tryAlertPerformance) ,please take a look at the `Known issues` in Readme file at first.

Comment: That sounds like some truly insane code. Why spin up a fresh thread just to have it message across to the main thread?

Comment: @MikeAbdullah All the alert messages must be sent to main thread if you want to display Alert windows according to Cocoa development.And you mean a fresh thread in the loop? As a matter of fact I tried it but the situation seems to be the same.

Comment: Correct, yes, alerts must be run on the main thread. What I don't understand from your code above is why you are detaching a *new* thread as well, which apparently does nothing but message across to the main thread

Comment: @MikeAbdullah The code above is JUST the simple sample from my project to show `NSRunAlertPanel` may have performance issue there.It indeed does nothing but can point out the symptom.

Comment: OK. It's incredibly hard to tell what you're really after here; having only small random fragments of code doesn't help. You likely need to go back to the drawing board: we generally use queues and `NSAlert` these days in Cocoa, rather than threads and `NSRunAlertPanel`.

Comment: @MikeAbdullah I've already put my sample on Github and have given the URL at the end of my question. To be honest, I don't think the project which I'd written contains ONLY small random fragments of codes.Our QA have reported the performance issue by hitting the AlertPanel continuously so that I made the question and did the sample, just made the `while` loop instead of operating by human beings.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the short answer is don't use `NSRunAlertPanel`. That family of functions have been discouraged for some time now, and superseded by `NSAlert`. Use `NSAlert` instead.

(Unfortunately the class reference for `NSRunAlertPanel` etc. doesn't mention this; I'm trying to remember where it was first documented; perhaps a release note)

Comment: There's a note in the intro to the [NSAlert](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation.